# How do I perform continuous orientation detection in ios?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have is a simple if statement to detect an orientation and perform an action.  This works well, but it only works the first time and it can't detect it again.

Does this `void` only get called once and if so, how can I change this around to constantly check?

Would I need to move some to `viewDidLoad`?

```
- (void) willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
    {
        [super willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:toInterfaceOrientation duration:duration];

        if (toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight)

        {
            [self.navigationController pushViewController:graphView animated:YES];

        }

            else if (toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft)
            {
                [self.navigationController pushViewController:graphView animated:YES];
            }

            else if (toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait)
            {
                [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
                NSLog(@"portrait");
            }

            else
            {
                [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];

            }

        }
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Im trying to switch back and forth between view controllers using a UINavigationController depending on the orientation

Comment: Is this code in your navigation controller or in the view controllers embedded in the nav controller?

Comment: It is in the first main view controller with the navigation controller embedded

Comment: is it because I load the new view controller and no longer can detect the orientation since that was in the last view controller?

Comment: You can detect the orientation regardless of view controller. Try putting this logic in the navigation controller though, since it is responsible for its child VC's.

Comment: btw - Paul Hegarty's iOS class from Stanford online?

Answer (score 1):

```
[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(orientationChanged:)
                                             name:@"UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification" 
                                           object:nil];
```

Comment: do I put that in view did load and then in the orientationChanged method create the if statements to detect the exact orientation?

Answer (score 1):

Expounding on what @Vjy wrote- 
One solution is to listen for device orientation notifications, and then find the new orientation and respond to it.

Before getting any device orientation notifications though, you **must** call

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice] beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];
```

or no notifications will be sent in the first place. After you begin generating orientation notifications, you have to listen for them.
You will need to tell each relevant view controller to listen for these notifications with

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                         selector:@selector(orientationDetected) //this is your function
                                             name:@"UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification" 
                                           object:nil];
```

then in `orientationDetected` or whatever you wish to name it-

```
- (void) orientationDetected
{
    switch ([[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation])
    {
        case UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft:
             // push appropriate view controller
             break;

        case UIDeviceOrientationPortrait:
             // and so on...
             break;
    }
}
```

You could also change your notification selector method to `@selector(methodThatReceivesNote:)` (note the colon) and have your method take a `(NSNotification*)` param, and then look through the `[paramName userInfo]` to find the relevant orientation, although I found very little info on what UIDevice notifications actually include in that `userInfo`.

You could also just research how to handle device orientation changes in a navigation controller's sub-views. I looked around a tiny bit, but I couldn't really find much about this. I'm sure the information is somewhere though, and this might be a more robust solution than notifications.